# How to serialize all li#id within an ul with jquery.serialize()?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, serialization

First of all, I am not using the jQuery-UI, only latest jQuery!

I have following list:

```
<ul id="audio_list">
    <li id="trackid_1"></li>
    <li id="trackid_5"></li>
    <li id="trackid_2"></li>
    <li id="trackid_4"></li>
    <li id="trackid_3"></li>
</ul>
```

Now I'd like to serialize this list and save it as an array in a variable, like:

```
var myaudiotracks = jQuery('#audio_list').serialize();
```

All I get is an empty string, of course, because I am missing something or it is not possible to serialize lists with jQuery only.

What I am trying to accomplish is to send this variable as an array to a PHP script, the result when posting the variable should be:

```
trackid[] 1
trackid[] 5
trackid[] 2
trackid[] 4
trackid[] 3
```

Any ideas how I can get to this result?

Comment: As per what i know the .serialize() works for the form elements having name-value pair. But not sure about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var array = jQuery('#audio_list li').map(function(){
    return 'trackid[]=' + this.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[1]
}).get()
console.log(array.join('&'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KUzBX/)

Comment: I marked this answer as the correct answer because it's very short, not using the each loop function and it is re-usable with other id's where needed if the id names differ. Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is to encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

Try using `.each()` and loop all `li` elements inside `div`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myaudiotracks = new Array();
    jQuery('#audio_list li').each(function(){
        myaudiotracks.push($(this).attr("id").split("trackid_")[1]);
    });
    console.log(myaudiotracks);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CUqkH/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can't use jQuery serialize function like this,it only works for the form elements,so if you want to get the result like that,try this:

```
<ul id="audio_list">
    <li id="trackid_1"><input type="hidden" name="trackid" value="1"></li>
    <li id="trackid_5"><input type="hidden" name="trackid" value="5"></li>
    <li id="trackid_2"><input type="hidden" name="trackid" value="2"></li>
    <li id="trackid_4"><input type="hidden" name="trackid" value="4"></li>
    <li id="trackid_3"><input type="hidden" name="trackid" value="3"></li>
```

```
var myaudiotracks = jQuery('#audio_list li').serialize();
```

Comment: using `name="trackid"` will only give you the last item. Use `name="trackid[]"` instead if you plan to use this method to serialize your data